# Adjust Next Date

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data set (df) with the following columns:

```html
ID Date  Next Date Datediff in days
1 2017-10-25 null  null
1 2016-12-13 2017-10-25 316
1 2016-11-23 2016-12-13 20
1 2016-11-14 2016-11-23 9
1 2015-07-07 2016-11-14 496
2 2015-05-15 null  null
2 2013-11-29 2015-05-15 532
2 2013-11-16 2013-11-29 13
2 2009-02-06 2013-11-16 1744
2 2006-06-21 2009-02-06 961
2 2002-06-25 2006-06-21 1457
```

In this case the "Next Date" is only valid if the date difference is greater than 30 days. Now I want to replace the next date entries with the valid next date and create a "New Next Date" column like this:

```html
ID Date  Next Date Datediff in days New Next Date
1 2017-10-25 null  null   null
1 2016-12-13 2017-10-25 316   2017-10-25
1 2016-11-23 2016-12-13 20   2017-10-25
1 2016-11-14 2016-11-23 9   2017-10-25
1 2015-07-07 2016-11-14 496   2016-11-14
2 2015-05-15 null  null   null
2 2013-11-29 2015-05-15 532   2015-05-15
2 2013-11-16 2013-11-29 13   2015-05-15
2 2009-02-06 2013-11-16 1744   2013-11-16
2 2006-06-21 2009-02-06 961   2009-02-06
2 2002-06-25 2006-06-21 1457   2006-06-21
```

I thought about using the lag function to create a helper column to replace dates that are smaller than 30 days. But it can happen for customer ID 1 that two invalid dates are successive. Then this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the lag function to add a column lagDate the, use when otherwise statement with [datediff](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#datediff) to compare difference:

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{when, col, lag, datediff, lag, date_add}
 val windowId = Window.partitionBy(col("ID")).orderBy("Date")
 val newDf =  df.withColumn("dateLimit", date_add(col("Date"), 30))
  .withColumn("lagDate1", lag(col("Date"), -1).over(windowId))
  .withColumn("lagDate2", lag(col("Date"), -2).over(windowId))
  .withColumn("lagDate", 
    when(datediff(col("lagDate1"), col("dateLimit")) >=0, col("lagDate1")).otherwise(col("lagDate2"))
  )
  .withColumn("correctNextDate",
    when(datediff(col("NextDate"), col("Date")) > 30 || col("NextDate").isNull,
      col("NextDate")).
      otherwise(col("lagDate"))
  )
```

Comment: That works partially if there is only 1 date to replace as for ID2. But it can also be the case that two entries have to be adjusted as happens for ID1.

Comment: can you be clearer ? you mean you may need lag(2) instead of lag(1) depending on the data ?

Comment: when I use your logic with lag(2), I receive in the "New Next Date" column in the 4. line "2016-12-13" instead of "2017-10-25". So basically if there are two entries in a row with less than 30 days, it would need to be adapted

Comment: it was a question not a suggestion for the lag(2) because I didn't understand the two entries problem you have mentionned. I'll run my code and get back to you

Comment: yes you are right, it needs to be lag(2) in my case and fits already to most cases. But unfortunately it doesn't work for ID 1 in my example. "2016-12-13" and "2016-11-23 " are both invalid "Next Date" entries based on the <30 days rule. The logic only replaces the first one correctly.

Comment: Ok I see. First I made a typo it's lag(-1). I updated the solution. It works but it's not clean

Comment: It works for my example, so I will mark it as solved. But for data with more than two invalid entries in a row, it might still be an open issue.